# Raspbmc loses connection to windows shared folder after sleep

Tags: smb, raspberry-pi, raspbmc

I have a Raspberry Pi with Raspbmc installed onto it (I have recently updated to the latest nightly build), and, after a bit of playing around, I have managed to get it to connect to a shared folder on my laptop which has video files in it.

However I have noticed that when I first turn on the Pi, or when it has been inactive for a period of time I cannot connect to the shared drive. The only way I have found to rectify this is to ssh onto the Pi, and ping my laptop. After doing this the shared folder can be connected to without issue.

Is there a setting somewhere to get it to maintain the connection properly or have I missed something else obvious!

Any help would be greatly appreciated as the experience of using the Pi is lessened by the need to have Putty on hand to wake it up all the time!

Duplicate posting: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5253/raspbmc-loses-connection-to-windows-shared-folder-after-inactivity

Comment: Belongs on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ ?  Possible duplicate there: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4773/raspberry-pi-sleep-mode-how-to-avoid ?

Comment: The question is perfectly fine for [su] and will not be migrated unless chillysapien requests it. Feel free to post an answer including information from the mentioned question on [raspberrypi] and referencing it.

Comment: I did post a possible duplicate.

Comment: Apologies, but I actually dual posted this on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5253/raspbmc-loses-connection-to-windows-shared-folder-after-inactivity. Feel free to close as duplicate if necessary